# Connecting to EPP Server from local system

Tags: php, fsockopen, epp

I am using fsock open to connect to epp server but its failing. Below is my code:(I have given wrong input values here.)

```
$whoisserver = "epp-test.verisign-grs.net";
$port = 123;
$timeout = 40;


$fp = @fsockopen($whoisserver, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout) or die("Socket Error " . $errno . " - " . $errstr);


$out = "";
while(!feof($fp)){
    $out .= fgets($fp, 128);
}

fclose($fp);


echo "<br> result <pre>\n" . $out . "\n</pre>\n <br>";
```

Below is the error which I am getting:

```
Socket Error 10060 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party 
did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Epp server gives reponse on connection. But the connection is failing.

I have also used CURL but not getting any response when using curl:(given wrong input values here)

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "epp-test.verisign-grs.net"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 123); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

 $res = curl_exec($ch); 
 echo "response is:<br>".$res."<br>";
 print "len[".strlen($res)."]\n"; 
 curl_close($ch);
```

Note: When I am doing ping to epp server from command line. Ping command is success I am getting reply from epp servers.

If am doing anything wrong ?

Can't we cannot to epp server from the local system?

Is SSL must be used to connect to epp server?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that data, server and port? EPP port is 700, you could've technically tested it with

```
openssl s_client -connect epp-test.verisign-grs.net:700
```

but Verisign is not allowing to connect to their server without special agreement made first and firewall rules established for you on their side.

If you just playing with EPP and trying to debug your scripts, you might consider CentralNIC, you must first ask them for username and password though.

For plain "greeting test" you might use:

```
openssl s_client -connect epp-ote.centralnic.com:700
```

Again, this will not work via curl. It might work in PHP with "ssl://epp-ote.centralnic.com" as your first argument. But you won't be able to get away with feof($fp) and other code without reading EPP specifications first:

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5730.txt
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5731.txt
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5732.txt
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5733.txt
- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5734.txt

Answer (score 0):

TLS is indeed mandatory for EPP, per [RFC5734](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5734.txt) :

> When layered over TCP, the Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol
>      version 1.0 [RFC2246] or its successors (such as TLS 1.2 [RFC5246]),
>      using the latest version supported by both parties, MUST be used to
>      provide integrity, confidentiality, and mutual strong client-server
>      authentication.